# On the integrability of uniform limit of sequence of integrable functions on infinite or semi infinite domains

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I know that the uniform limit $f$ of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of integrable functions defined on $[a,b]$ is integrable and $$\int_a^b f dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n dx,$$
Also, this result will not work when the domain is different from $[a,b]$. For instance, there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ of  integrable functions on $[0,\infty)$ and its uniform limit $f$ where $\int_a^b f dx \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n dx.$

But, I could not find a non-integrable uniform limit for a sequence of integrable functions on a domain such as $[0,\infty)$ or $\Bbb R$. What we can conclude about the integrability of such uniform limits? Of course, we have non-integrable point wise limits like Dirichlet function for sequence of integrable functions, but what about uniform limits?

Comment: sorry I didn't read the last part :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f_n (x)=\frac 1x \chi_{(1,n)}$, $f(x)=\frac  1x$ for $x>1$.

Comment: But the limit is integrable on $(1,\infty)$, right?

Comment: It is certainly not. @Riaz

Comment: Ya....I got it....